# How to set environment variables in torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel?

Tags: pytorch

I am trying to train my code with distributed data parallelism, I already trained using `torch.nn.DataParallel` and now I am trying to see how much gain I can get in training speed if I train using `torch.nn.parallel.DistributedDataParallel` since I read on numerous pages that its better to use DistributedDataParallel. So I followed one of the examples but I am not sure how to set the following environment variables (`os.environ['MASTER_ADDR']` and `os.environ['MASTER_PORT']`) since I am using a cloud service so I am not sure which specific node my code gets allocated for training my model. Can anyone help me to set these variables?

Comment: I have the exact same question, did you get an answer?